# Is a php filter available for Drupal 10.1.2?

Tags: installation, 10

Its been a few years since I've used Drupal (pretty much missing version 9), but I'm coming back to it with 10.1.2. I'm hoping to get a PHP filter installed for content, as I historically like to use PHP to include dynamic contents from non-Drupal sources.

Unfortunately, chasing down how to do this has been leading me in circles most of the morning, from the original filter in the 6/7 timeframe to apparently an optional core model in the 8/9 timeframe, but I've yet to find something for version 10 specifically, and Google searches using the version number happily pulls up earlier documentation.

Can someone provide a pointer to this functionality, if it exists, for 10.1.2?

Comment: Will will struggle greatly with Drupal's modern cache system by using the PHP module.

Comment: The answer is 'Yes'. It is available here: https://www.drupal.org/project/php/issues/3363035.

Comment: That issue is not completed. The answer is “No”. The module is not yet ported to Drupal 10.

Answer (score 1):

No. At the time I write this the PHP module is [not yet ported to Drupal 10](https://www.drupal.org/project/php/issues/3363035).

Answer (score 1):

Running PHP code via the PHP input filter has been considered a source of security issues; that is why the PHP input filter has been removed from Drupal core.
It has been moved to a contributed module, in the [PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/php) project, but it has been created to help people migrate away from the PHP input filter. That is why the *PHP* project is not covered by security advisory policy, and the [existing releases](https://www.drupal.org/project/php/releases) have been marked insecure.
It would not probably get a Drupal 10 release too.

Instead of using the PHP input filter, you need to create a module that implement the necessary hooks, services, controllers, or forms. A module can do everything the code handled by the PHP input filter can do, and much more.

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal 9 version appears to install fine also on Drupal 10, on what I have tested, does not need any special porting. However I haven't tested it thoroughly but works fine in Views and Blocks at least. Caching etc likely does not work but nevertheless running it on a couple of sites. But as mentioned earlier in the previous replies, this is not recommended so do it only on your own risk and only if you are sure of what you are doing.

The way to get this running on drupal 10 is to edit the configuration php.info.yml to allow installation on Drupal 10, aka "core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9 || ^10".